# Numpy - Length of values (1191) does not match length of index (1250)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, facebook-prophet

would appreciate any help with this, I'm getting and error of
ValueError: Length of values (1191) does not match length of index (1250).

I don't understand where Numpy is getting the length of 1191 from ?, I've created a Dataframe of 1250, and I'm trying to assign future['floor'] to it based on conditions, future['cap'] works fine, but that is Pandas, whereas 'Floor' is using NP, but I don't understand why NP would cause this error. Thanks for your help. Gav

```
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=1250,freq='D', include_history=False)
   
conditions = [
g['Operator'] == 100151,
g['Operator'] == 20137,
g['Operator'] == 20147,  
]
values = [
   g['y'].mean()/2,
    g['y'].mean()/2,
    g['y'].mean()/2
]
future['floor'] = np.select(conditions,values)

future['cap'] = max(g['y'])*1.25    

forecast = m.predict(future)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-184-a698f789f6b3> in <module>
----> 1 fout = df.groupby('Operator').apply(forecast_data)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    892         with option_context("mode.chained_assignment", None):
    893             try:
--> 894                 result = self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
    895             except TypeError:
    896                 # gh-20949

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f, data)
    926             data after applying f
    927         """
--> 928         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, data, self.axis)
    929 
    930         return self._wrap_applied_output(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in apply(self, f, data, axis)
    236             # group might be modified
    237             group_axes = group.axes
--> 238             res = f(group)
    239             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes, axis):
    240                 mutated = True

<ipython-input-183-f88148e0e94e> in forecast_data(g)
     42         g['y'].mean()/2
     43     ]
---> 44     future['floor'] = np.select(conditions,values)
     45     future['cap'] = max(g['y'])*1.25
     46     forecast = m.predict(future)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3161         else:
   3162             # set column
-> 3163             self._set_item(key, value)
   3164 
   3165     def _setitem_slice(self, key: slice, value):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3240         """
   3241         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3242         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3243         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3244 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3897 
   3898             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 3899             value = sanitize_index(value, self.index)
   3900             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   3901                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index)
    749     """
    750     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 751         raise ValueError(
    752             "Length of values "
    753             f"({len(data)}) "

ValueError: Length of values (1191) does not match length of index (1250)
```

Comment: Could you show the backtrace?  Where is the error occurring?

Comment: Thanks, as I'm only ever assigning a single value to future['floor'] is there anyway just to pass it 1250 times ?

Comment: What is `g`? and Is it possible `g` is length 1191 while `future` is 1250?

Comment: Hi 'g' is a Grouped Dataframe of daily transactions 'y' , but the Pandas line of  future['cap'] = max(g['y'])*1.25  doesn't produce a mismatch, I only get a mismatch when I use NP to return the condition.

Comment: Right because `max(g['y'])*1.25` is a scalar, but `np.select(conditions,values)` is only going to produce an array as long as `g`. Which _would_ cause a ValueError when you attempt `future['floor'] = np.select(conditions,values)` if they do not match in length.

Comment: I agree w/ @HenryEcker that the problem here is almost certainly that `g` is the wrong length

Comment: thank you, is there an easy way to get np.select(conditions,values) to pass 1250 ? by adding to or truncating the g array length ?, or since the value max(g['y']) is always going to be constant just taking the first value and passing that as an array of 1250 ?